# how to dump sql.gz file in to mysql

Tags: linux, mysql, compression

I have allocated almost all of my space on the production server to my table space

Now i have an compressed dump of around 20gb which is needed to be dumped into mysql

The problem is the server is not having much space to uncompress the file (which requires around 120 gb)

i have used the beolw command but i am a failure because it is first uncompressing the file and then redirecting the output to mysql

```
 gunzip dbdump.sql.gz | mysql -u root -proot123 -S /home/mysql55/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Is there any way so that i can dump the compressed file without uncompressing it

any suggestions are really grateful

Answer (score 17):

You should tell `gunzip` to write to standard out. What you are doing right now is not going to pipe any output at all.

```
gunzip -c dbdump.sql.gz | mysql (args...)
```

Comment: thanks it is working fine and is there any similar way for sql.tar.gz file

Comment: I've never encountered such a `sql.tar.gz` file, but if you mean a `tar.gz` file that contains a `sql` file, then it would be `tar -zvxOf somefile.tar.gz path/to/sql/file | mysql ...`.

Comment: Why the `path/to/sql/file`? I imported my file with just `tar -zvxOf dump.tgz|mysql database -u ...`
`

Comment: I thought he was talking about a `tar.gz` file that contained a `sql` file inside it somewhere. Your file is just a normal gzipped sql file so you can use the `gunzip` command as well.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is ridiculous, but it was gzipped twice, so

1. Extract `filename.sql.gz`
2. Rename extracted file from `filename.sql` to `filename.gz`
3. Extract again

Hope it will work

Answer (score 3):

We can achieve the same with the below command as well. Here i am using gzip

```
gzip -d < dbdump.sql.gz | mysql (args..)
```

Another way is as given below

```
gzip -c dbdump.sql.gz | mysql (args..)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can import using this.

```
zcat dbdump.sql.gz | mysql -u username -p dbname
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to uncompress the file on the fly, in example:

```
$ cat dbdump.sql.gz | gzip -cd | mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting gunzip. Here is one for windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gzip.htm

Once you unzip, you can upload your .sql